# How do I permanently disable logging in Outlook 365 for Mac

Tags: macos, ms-office, storage, logs

I ran into an weird issue today when I was prompted that I was running out of space on my disk.  Digging into the issue I found that Outlook has been generating a debug log so much that it chewed through almost 200GB of data in plain text.

Weird thing is logging is not enabled when I checked the settings and I can't seem to find an answer as to why it keeps generating the logs.  Deleting the log, stop, and then start Outlook again creates a new log file that hits over 200MB in less than 6 minutes. After about an hour it became over 1GB already.

How do I stop this non-stop generation of logs?

Comment: 200GB or 200mb? Can you try reinstalling the app after standard uninstall method?

Comment: It was almost 200 GB when I first noticed the issue.  After deleting that log file, upon restart of Outlook, it generated over 200MB of log in less than 10 min.  After about an hour it's over 1GB already.

I can't test with the reinstall right now but I'll try that later tonight.  The account in question is a google apps email account.

Answer (score 1):

To disable logging:

Restart Outlook and when prompted to turn off logging click "Turn Logging Off"

If you disable logging manually you must restart Outlook to fully disable logging, otherwise, it will continue logging in the background

Comment: The logging was never enabled in the first place.  The Apparently logging was enabled automatically when I installed Outlook.  I've tried the disable logging process a couple times already before I came on here and not once have I gotten the "disable logging" message on Outlook startup.

Now this is a corporate managed machine (did not come with Office, I installed that separately as it's not a standard issue software), would force logging be a possible culprit?

Comment: That's likely to be the case. This process is for Outlook thats included with Office. You may need to contact Microsoft support.

Answer (score 1):

So my issue ended up being a borked forced profile from work that they're refusing to fix since I'm using Office356 instead of OpenOffice.  Something they set is forcing debug logging to be enabled but not show as being enabled in the setting....